# How to 'convert' amount of Hz to appropriate byte/bit format?

Tags: c++, bit-shift, hardware

I am programming an IR camera. But the internal register for storing the refreshrate (bits 9, 8 and 7 of 16 in total) only accepts 1's and 0's of course. For example, a value of 0b110 means 32Hz and 0b111, 64Hz. How can I best convert a given integer (`refresh_rate`) value between 0.5Hz and 64Hz to 0b000 - 0b111 when looking at the Refresh rate control picture?

[image]

To be honest, I haven't tried anything yet because I think it requires a weird hack. However I have been thinking of a lookuptable, I think that is possible but requires more memory and it has to be memory efficient since it is programmed on an Arduino Due.

Note: You can see that the refresh_rate is an `uint16_t` which does not accept floating point values such as 0.5Hz, however, I am probably not going to use the 0.5Hz setting.

```cpp
// the end-user currently has to pass a value between 7 and 0
void mlx90650::set_refresh_rate(uint16_t refresh_rate) {
    // So the refresh rate may not be higher than 7 (0b111) since this register only 
accepts 3 bits. The memory map is:
/*
    | decimal | bits  |  
    (decimal 0) 0 0 0 IR refresh rate = 0.5Hz 
    (decimal 1) 0 0 1 IR refresh rate = 1Hz 
    (decimal 2) 0 1 0 IR refresh rate = 2Hz (default) 
    (decimal 3) 0 1 1 IR refresh rate = 4Hz 
    (decimal 4) 1 0 0 IR refresh rate = 8Hz 
    (decimal 5) 1 0 1 IR refresh rate = 16Hz 
    (decimal 6) 1 1 0 IR refresh rate = 32Hz 
    (decimal 7) 1 1 1 IR refresh rate = 64H
*/
}
```

I want that this function converts for example 64Hz to 0b111.

Comment: I use enums for things like this, and then have a switch to convert from the enum to the specific bit pattern.  (I try NOT to have the enum reflect the bit pattern, so that the specific enum values do not have semantic meaning.)  `enum class RefreshRate { kDefault /* same as k2Hz */, kHalfHz, k1Hz, k2Hz, k4Hz, k8Hz, k16Hz, k32Hz, k64Hz };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I best convert a given integer (refresh_rate) value between 0.5Hz and 64Hz to 0b000 - 0b111

One approach is to see that the target value increases by one every time the input doubles, meaning it is *log<sub>2</sub>(Hz) + 1*.

So, you can write

```
uint16_t hz_bits(float hz) {
    return static_cast<uint16_t>(round(1.0f + log2(hz)));
}
```

which admittedly requires floating-point and isn't highly-optimized. Conversely,

```
float hz_from_bits(uint16_t hzB) {
    return 0.5f * (1 << hzB);
}
```

Both of those have the three bits you care about as the least significant bits of the `uint16_t`.

If you want to use an integral Hz number, and ignore the `0.5` case, then *log<sub>2</sub>* is just the number of the highest set bit: eg, 64 = 0b1000000, with highest set bit 6 (you still need to add 1 to get 7 = 0b111).

Then you can combine them with something like

```
static const uint16_t HZ_START = 7;
static const uint16_t HZ_LEN = 3;
static const uint16_t HZ_MASK = ((1 << HZ_LEN)-1) << HZ_START;

uint16_t set_hz_bits(uint16_t control, uint16_t hzB) {
    return (control & ~HZ_MASK) | (hzB << HZ_START);
}
uint16_t get_hz_bits(uint16_t control) {
    return (control & HZ_MASK) >> HZ_START;
}
```

into

```
uint16_t set_hz(uint16_t control, float hz) {
    return set_hz_bits(control, hz_bits(hz));
}
float get_hz(uint16_t control) {
    return hz_from_bits(get_hz_bits(control));
}
```

Note that the actual bit masking and shifting is pretty mechanical - you can automate this stuff for your various fields quite easily, using something like the below, and pass around `HzField` objects instead of having to remember which `uint16_t` contain zero-based encoded Hz values, and which contain correctly layed-out control registers.

```
template <size_t Bstart, size_t Blen, typename T = uint16_t>
struct BitField
{
    T value; // zero-based, not shifted

    static constexpr T mask() { return ((1 << Blen)-1) << Bstart; }

    static T clear(T r) { return r & ~mask(); }

    void decode(T r) { value = (r & mask()) >> Bstart; }
    T encode(T r) { return clear(r) | ((value << Bstart) & mask()); }
    // etc.
};
using HzField = BitField<7, 3>;
```

Answer (score 2):

First convert the Hz value in the register to a number:

```
register_value >>= 7;  // Shift right 7 bits.
register_value &= 7;  // Keep remaining 3 bits.
```

Next, calculate the Hz by left shifting.

```
herz = (1 << register_value) / 2.;
```

To set the Herz value, perform the *opposite* (reverse) steps.

Comment: I tested it and it works, however, with a `register_value` of `0b1110000000` this gives me an output of 128Hz, so I think you might have dropped a `-1` somewhere or my registers weren't correctly transferred. I'm also having a hard time understanding the opposite (reverse) steps you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

However you map actual Hz to bit patterns, you set them like this:

```
void set_hz(uint16_t& control_reg, uint8_t hz)  // here hz is 0 for .5 Hz, 1 for 1Hz,.. 7 for 64Hz
{
     constexpr int hz_shift = 7;
     constexpr uint16_t hz_mask = static_cast<uint16_t>(0x07) << hz_shift;
     control_reg &= ~hz_mask;
     control_reg |= static_cast<uint16_t>(hz) << hz_shift;
}
```